# Which one stores more energy? CNG or LPG?

Tags: energy, gas

I tried to learn about gas power and googled to find out which one has the higher energy density. And it seems like sources directly contradict each other. For instance, I found an energy density of [13,3kWh/L for CNG and 6,8kWh/L for LPG](https://www.erdgas.info/erdgas-mobil/alternative-kraftstoffe/vergleich-cng-und-lpg/), but I also found a value of [9MJ/L for CNG and 25MJ/L for LPG](https://www.elgas.com.au/blog/1698-cng-vs-lpg-comparing-properties-sources-uses-homes-cars-vehicles). These values seem to be directly contradicting each other. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Did you convert at least the units? Is this a homework question?

Comment: No just purely personal curiosity. But the units are key, you're right

Answer (score 1):

I had to translate your first link, but you actually copied it wrong.

It says $13.3 \frac {\text{kWh}}{\text{kg}}$ for the first, and $6.8 \frac {\text{kWh}}{\text{L}}$ for the second.  They are comparing litres to kilograms, because that is how each is sold respectively.  They don't contradict, they just aren't quite comparing the energy density because they choose to compare energy density of one with specific energy of the other.

That seems a bit dishonest to me, but I only skimmed the article, so I don't know if they were just doing that to show the economy of it or what (but then it would have been more fair to convert both to approximate cost per $\text{MJ}$ or $\text{kWh}$ instead of comparing two things that aren't the same).

Your second set of values seem to be the correct values for $\frac {\text{MJ}}{\text{L}}$.

Comment: I copied them from the graphic below the text, but it was late in the evening and I didn't notice I guess. Thank you for noticing and taking the time to clarify.

Comment: @scrrr Saying CNG has double energy density seems plain wrong to me too.  Using the actual definition of "energy density", LPG has ~1.55 x the energy density of CNG (energy per unit volume).  CNG has ~10% more specific energy (energy per unit mass) than LPG; but that is nowhere near the 100% difference they are claiming.  I have to say that comparing specific energy to energy density and concluding one has "double the energy density of the other" is at _very least_ a pretty big misunderstanding of the science, or at worst was done to purposefully mislead people.